# Docker Spring Boot Postgres Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

It is my first time trying to put my Springboot application into one docker container and my PostgresDB into another container.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/esteticcenter
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8082
RUN mkdir -p /app/
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs/
ADD target/postgres-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=esteticcenter
    restart: unless-stopped
  # APP*****************************************
  springbootapp:
    image: springbootapp:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: springbootapp
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Error: *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.*

I tried to replace the "localhost" with dbpostgresql or db but in spring.datasource.url like many answers I checked but then "mvn clean package" fails and I can not create the jar. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker compose will create a dedicated network with DNS for your services. Each service will get the service name as hostname (as defined in docker-compose.yml).
Other containers can be accessed from inside this network by their service name.

Changing the hostname for the database in your `application.properties` file should fix the issue:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/esteticcenter
```

Comment: My mvn clean package then fails and I can not create the jar. Please read the last sentece.

Comment: Are you running tests with the same properties file? If so, you should create a separate configuration for deploying (or testing). Or you can leave the default property, and overwrite it in the docker-compose.yml file as an environment variable (just like the user & password properties)

Comment: Hello @Pieterjan. When another user run my docker image, it gives this error  "o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections." Can you help me?

Comment: Is this user also running PostgreSQL? Always configure the datasource URL with the appropriate hostname. If you are running locally, this can be 'localhost'. If you run in Docker compose, this will be the name of the database services, e.g. 'postgress'. If the database is running on a different host (server/computer), you will need to use the host name or IP address of this device instead.